# Python subprocess and os doesn't run .exe file with other file that .exe requires

Tags: python, json, operating-system, subprocess, exe

I'm making an automatic updating system, that reads a link from website and if this link is different that older link, it's open and download file from link and after update, runs the main .exe, but i tried some solutions envolving os, subprocess... And all of these doesn't allow the main exe recognize a json file in same directory, but executting this .exe outside python, it's recognize. How can i call this exe and make it recognize others files in same directory?

I've tried these:

```
path_unzip = 'D:\Test'
path_program = 'Consults.exe'
subprocess.Popen([f"{path_unzip}\{path_program}"])
subprocess.Popen([f"{path_unzip}\{path_program}"], env=dict(os.environ, PATH=path_unzip))
subprocess.run([f"{path_unzip}\{path_program}"], env=dict(os.environ, PATH=path_unzip))
subprocess.run([f'{path_unzip}\{path_program}', "-c", "pass"])
os.system(f'"{path_unzip}\{path_program}"')
os.system(f'start "{path_unzip}\{path_program}"')
os.system(f'cd "{path_unzip}" && start "{path_program}"')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide a [mre] including debugging details such as the log of the child process and listing of the working directory of that child process. Did you check all of the required files are in the proper directories and the child process accesses them properly? Anyway, did you try the ```cwd``` argument of the ```subprocess.run()``` or ```subprocess.Popen()```?

Comment: In Python, nothing happens indicating an error, but the exe returns an popup informing that doesn't find the .json file that is inside in the same directory that exe, but when i've tried to execute by clicking using just file explorer, works... I'm going to test the cwd argument that you mentioned! OBS: The .exe file is an compiled python code!

Comment: Cwd argument for subprocess works! I've added the argument and modified all "\" for "\\" on the path string... Thanks and sorry for my bad english, i'm Brazilian :)

Comment: If you have solved, what about answering your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Was just the path with single "/".
Path strings must use double "/", like this: "//".